# How to make a square chart?

Tags: highcharts

I would like my chart to be square (equal lengths of the x and y axis). I tried to use

```
#chart {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
}
```

in order to force the size of the chart - it works, but for the whole chart, including the labels (they are taken into account when setting the width or height, effectively shortening one side the chart by their size).

Is there a way to influence the size of the actual chart area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - make sure that your outer chart dimensions account for the margins of each of the four sides.

In this example:

```
   chart : { 
        margin : [100,50,100, 200],
        width  : 550,
        height : 500
    }
```

I have set the margins explicitly, so I can then know what size the plot area will be by subtracting the margins from the dimensions.

In this case, the margins add 50px extra to the width, so I make the chart 50px wider than it is tall, and get a plot area that is 300px square.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ymwfgwpk/